# ASP.NET Web Application Restarting When Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have created an ASP.NET web application (4.7.2) in Visual Studio 2019. When it starts up, using the Entity framework (6.2.0), it talks to a database and retrieves some information from a table. However once that operation has completed the web application restarts i.e. WebApiApplication::Application_End gets called.

After some investigation it turns out .edmx files are being created in the bin folder when the application starts and because the content of the bin folder has changed the web application restarts. When it starts again those same .edmx files are recreated, the contents of the bin folder has therefore changed and therefore the web application restart again.

I then created a console application to see if I had the same problem. The first time I run it the .edmx files are created, however when I run it again the .edmx are NOT recreated.

So I guess my question is what are the possible reasons these .edmx files are being recreated every time I start the web application?

Comment: What have you got in your startup code? edmx files shouldn't be recreated unless you explicitly say so.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when run using Local IIS it is fine but when run using IIS Express it is not (Project -> Properties -> Web -> Servers).